# Found nil when unwrapping optional value in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've been trying to address this issue for a few days and it seems I'm only going in circles.

I'm adding data to core data by tapping on `tableView` cells and then displaying the items on another `tableView`.

That works great, the problem is this:

When I click on the other table view rows, to be able to see the item with all the other values stored in core data, I get

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the showMeTheGoodiesTwo(entry: myCart) line
```

...Inside `viewDidLoad`. But I do not know why that's happening, as the entity is not empty.

Here's the code of the view controller where I want to display the item's details.

Hope somebody can give me a hand.

Cheers!

```
import UIKit

class productQuantityViewController: UIViewController {

    var myCart: Cart!

    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productAmountLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var minusButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        productImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        minusButton.layer.cornerRadius = minusButton.frame.size.width/2
        plusButton.layer.cornerRadius = plusButton.frame.size.width/2

        showMeTheGoodiesTwo(entry: myCart)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func showMeTheGoodiesTwo(entry: Cart) {

        let name = entry.product
        let quantity = entry.inventory
        let description = entry.productDescription

        let image = entry.productImage as Data?
        let xNSNumber = quantity as NSNumber

        productNameLabel!.text = name
        productDescriptionLabel!.text = description
        productAmountLabel!.text = xNSNumber.stringValue
        productImage!.image = UIImage(data:image!)

        print(productNameLabel.text as Any)

    }


}
```

Comment: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unripping an Optional value..."  Set the record straight.  I have never seen an error like the one you've mentioned.  I have seen 'while unwrapping,' not 'not 'while unripping.'

Comment: Cheers mate, didn't know people were so precious here with typos, I'll get it fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
var myCart: Cart!
```

To

```
var myCart: Cart?
```

? is use to make it optional.
And in viewDidLoad use

```
if (myCart != nil){
            showMeTheGoodiesTwo(entry: myCart)
        } else {
            //do something.
        }
```

instead of

```
showMeTheGoodiesTwo(entry: myCart)
```

Comment: thats awesome, it works great thanks although theres a new issue now... the segue happens and the other view controller shows but it displays no data at all. Any idea why could that be?

Comment: Your object myCart not receiving data from your previous view controller.

Comment: If Answer is work for you please accept and upvote it .

Comment: Cool thanks mate! Jut quickly how can it be that myCart is not getting any data from my other view controller if I can see the data itself on the table view?

Comment: You need to check your didSelectRowAtIndexPath function if it pass data or not.

Comment: great help, I was missing a line of code to pass the date, thanks heaps!

Comment: I did but it's not showing as I don't have 15 point of reputation now...